# Template standard values final layout

Tags: best-practices, presentation, templates

Which purposes can be reached by using final layout in template standard values?
What are advantages and disadvantages to use final layout in template standard values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really an opinion based answer, but the only advantage I see is the ability to have different presentation per language variant on the standard values of the template.

This could have potential side effects tho, it would not always be obvious that each language variant had different presentation and I think this would be a rare case and could probably be handled better with personalization rule on the shared layout.

I would probably make it a rule to *not* use the final layout on the standard values of a template.

Comment: "I would probably make it a rule to not use the shared layout on the standard values of a template." Do you mean final or shared?

Comment: ha - good catch, I mean final. Answer updated.

Comment: yes, it is better to avoid using final layout in templates. Sometimes this causes really strange issues with presentation editing (on content items) in addition to the fact it is not supposed to be used on standard values by design.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the requirements.

#### Worth to use when...

you have for example a page template, let's call it `Article Page` and you have a multi language site (english and german).

If the english page should look different (order of the renderings or totally different renderings) like the german in most cases or even every case when authors create a new `Article Page` then it makes sense to use Final Layouts for Standard Values.

Let's define the Renderings. A rendering could be also a "layout" which use only placeholders, for example:

- Rendering 1: Sidebar and MainContent (english)
- Rendering 2: MainContent and Sidebar (german)

I would not say to use just maybe in rare cases.

Comment: So, you saying creating __standardValues in English and German languages and setting final layout? is creating __standardValues in different languages a good idea?

Comment: Thanks, Actually this worked, I have created a new German version of __standardValue and and set a different final layout. When i create an item based on that template shared layout and final layout is the final layout i set in __standardValue. But its weird, Shared Layout is shared. It should be same for all languages and verisons?

Comment: You can use totally different presentation in the Final Layout. You can add more Renderings to the Final layout or even delete Renderings which are in the Shared layout. Final layout is a kind of merge of Final Layout and Shared Layout but Final Layout is stronger.

Comment: The weird issue i found is, when i set the final layout in __standardValues for german. The item which was created by this template in German has shared and final layout set as final layout in __standardValues. Shared Layout is shared field, this should be same as other languages right. But its not?